# C++ : defining a two-dimensional array of a inner-class struct

Tags: c++, arrays, class, struct

I am trying to build a window controller for SDL with its own pseudo-pixels. I had the code working using a single big and ugly translation unit, but am now trying to refactor the same code into multiple units and classes.

In this class, I am attempting to define the controller for the window, and I am having trouble understanding how to work with a nested structure inside a class.

The errors I am getting are on the line `Pixel* pixels[][];`. The compiler complains that "*incomplete type is not allowed*". The struct seems to be fully defined in the .cpp.
The second error is that "*an array may not have elements of this type*"; I understand that the second dimension of an array has to be of a defined size, but how do I define this size at compile-time while keeping my code flexible for windows of different sizes?

```
//PxWindow.h

#include <SDL.h>

class PxWindow {
    struct Pixel {
        static int PARENT_PIXEL_SIZE;
        // Data members
        int x, y;
        Color color;
        
        // Methods
        int screenX();
        int screenY();
        SDL_Rect getPixelRect();
    };
//  Private Data Member declarations
private:
    int PIXEL_SIZE;
    int NUM_PIXELS_X;
    int NUM_PIXELS_Y;

//  Public Data Member declarations
public:
    Pixel* pixels[][];
    SDL_Rect rects[][];

public:
    PxWindow(int,int,int);
    int getPixelSize();
    int getNumX();
    int getNumY();
};
```

```
//   PxWindow.cpp

#include "PxWindow.h"
/*
 *  Pixel Structure method definitions
 */
SDL_Rect PxWindow::Pixel::getPixelRect() {
    return SDL_Rect{ screenX(), screenY(), PARENT_PIXEL_SIZE, PARENT_PIXEL_SIZE };
};
int PxWindow::Pixel::screenX() { return x * PARENT_PIXEL_SIZE; }
int PxWindow::Pixel::screenY() { return y * PARENT_PIXEL_SIZE; }


/*
 *  PxWindow Class method definitions
 */
PxWindow::PxWindow(int px_size, int num_x, int num_y) : 
    PIXEL_SIZE(px_size), 
    NUM_PIXELS_X(num_x), 
    NUM_PIXELS_Y(num_y) {
    Pixel::PARENT_PIXEL_SIZE = PIXEL_SIZE;
};

int PxWindow::getPixelSize() {
    return PIXEL_SIZE;
};
int PxWindow::getNumX() {
    return NUM_PIXELS_X;
};
int PxWindow::getNumY() {
    return NUM_PIXELS_Y;
};
```

Comment: _"...Because array elements cannot be arrays of unknown bound, multidimensional arrays cannot have unknown bound in a dimension other than the first:..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array

Comment: I understand that error-- of course every dimension of an array besides the first must be defined at compile time. My question was precisely:
"*..how do I define this size at compile-time while keeping my code flexible for windows of different sizes?*"

Comment: Your statement contradicts itself. "Define this size at compile-time" means that it's fixed to a specific size, and cannot change at runtime, for "windows of different sizes". These two statements cannot both be true.

Comment: @Sam, you're right. I should have asked more generally how I can get this to compile while leaving it flexible for windows of different sizes to be created at runtime.

Comment: This is what `std::vector` is for. Do you know how to use `std::vector`? If not, you will find more information in your C++ textbook.

Comment: Just a caution about terminology: C++ doesn't formally have a notion of "inner" class; it has **nested** classes. Inner classes are a Java thing, and they have somewhat peculiar semantics that have no counterpart in C++.

Comment: @Sam I do know how to use vectors but I was worried they would draw more memory than an array-only approach.

Comment: @PeteBecker I appreciate the clarification, I do have more experience with Java than I do C++. I'll read up on nested classes.

Comment: Then create a 1D vector, and provide a light wrapper that translates 2d coordinates into a single 1d index, and references the appropriate value in the vector. Same amount of memory used as an array. Problem solved.

Comment: @Sam Excellent approach! Thank you very much for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error:
You should check your includes. Most likely one is missing to complete your struct "Pixel". You seem to use SDL_Rect, but I can't see the include for SDL in your header file.

For your second error:
To make the array a little more dynamic you would have to create a new array (arrayTwo) of array.size() + 1 and copy all data from array to arrayTwo yourself.
You could also use a  (or two nested vectors for 2d), but it depends on your performance needs.

Comment: I have edited the question to provide includes, as they are there in the original code.
I appreciate this array-only solution to the variable length array problem.
I will also do some research on the memory usage of vectors; that seems like a more workable approach if its not too heavy.